# How to use user defined column names for calculating a field in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel vba, to make a pivot table. After I build my pivot using the two columns in the value section of pivot "Value MAT19" and "Volume(Kg) MAT 19", I want to add a derived field i.e 'Value MAT19'/'Volume(Kg) MAT 19' to the pivot. However I don't want to fix the column names myself instead give user the control to select the columns in the pivot (it could be Value MAT18 or Value MAT17 and similarly for the Volume column) and hence I am using the InputBox feature of VBA. But I after I run my macro the calculated field does not show up. Here is the code I wrote for it. I have declared myValue and myVolume as String variables. The column Final API is getting displayed in the pivot but Final Val/Vol is not showing up.

```
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CalculatedFields.Add "Final Val/Vol", _
        "=myValue /myVolume", True
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Final Val/Vol"). _
        Orientation = xlDataField

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CalculatedFields.Add "FinalAPI", _
        "='Value MAT19' /'Volume(Kg) MAT 19'", True
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("FinalAPI").Orientation = _
        xlDataField
```

EDIT: This is the code that I have added according to Cyril's suggestion, but it still doesn't add the "Final Val/Vol" column.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").CalculatedFields.Add "Final Val/Vol", _
    "=" & myValue & "/" & myVolume, True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Final Val/Vol"). _
    Orientation = xlDataField
```

This is where I add myValue and myVolume and ask use for input, also declaring default column values:

```
    Dim myVolume As String
    Dim myValue As String

    myVolume = InputBox("Please enter volume column name", "Volume", "Volume(Kg) MAT 19")
    myValue = InputBox("Please enter value column name", "Value", "Value MAT19")
```

Comment: you need to have your input box value captured and used as opposed to hard coding, e.g., your formula would look like `"=" & inputcol1 & "/" & inputcol2`

Comment: where did you define `myValue` and `myVolume`?   it may come down to syntax... what was the error you received when trying to run your code?

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion, I have added the code in edit, I am not getting any errors the code runs fine, however the desired column is not added.

Comment: I believe I left out the apostrophe in the syntax for a column... try `"='" & myValue & "'/'" & myVolume & "'"`

Comment: It worked now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comments as answer to close-out this resolved issue:

---

Try:

```
"='" & myValue & "'/'" & myVolume & "'"
```

The inputbox values need captured as variables and then used with appropriate syntax, e.g., `'column_name'`